# Flutter Google Maps plugin is not working properly on iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, flutter, google-maps-markers

I'm using this Google Maps plugin: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter

On Android it's working fine, but markers on iOS are not working properly. When a marker is tapped on iOS platform, camera moves a little bit and displays an InfoText, but my flutter code is the same for both platforms. I put breakpoints on methods: **onMarkerTapped()** and **onInfoWindowTapped()** and there are not called on iOS devices (GoogleMapController.dart).

Also the marker icon providing a BitmapDescriptor is not working on iOS too, but it's not as important as all I've mentioned before.

**- Someone knows how to call this methods on iOS?**

Please, I need to fix this on iOS platform and I don't know how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the project readme (emphasis mine):

> This plugin provides an unpublished preview of the Flutter API for
>   Google Maps:
>
> Dart APIs for controlling and interacting with a GoogleMap view from Flutter code are still being consolidated and expanded. The
>   intention is to grow current coverage into a complete offering. Issues
>   and pull requests aimed to help us prioritize and speed up this effort
>   are very welcome.
>       **Currently the plugin only supports Android** as it embeds a platform view in the Flutter hierarchy which is currently only supported for
>   Android (tracking issue).

iOS is not yet supported for this plugin. Likely you will just have to wait until the plugin is out of preview - or at least closer to release when it is more feature complete. I wouldn't recommend using such a preview in production.

One alternative I have found some success with is https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_map It has worked ok for me, but does have some hiccups with performance at times.

Comment: It's April 2019 and the plugin still does not work properly on iOS 

Comment: march 2021 now. latest version of google maps still crashes on iOS.

Comment: any solutions to this yet?

Comment: I haven't used maps in flutter in quite a while, but looking at the package, it looks like iOS is supported now. Why not give it a try and see?